# Return a Scala value as a Json string

Tags: json, scala, playframework

In Play Framework, I have the following method in the controller:

```
def country(countryCode: String) =
    Authorized().async { implicit request =>
      val country = Country.find(countryCode).get
    
      val countryPostcodeZones = postcodeZones.get(country)
    
      val placeholder = countryPostcodeZones.postcodeType.placeholder  
    }
```

How can I return this as a Json string to see it on my localhost, in response to an Ajax request?

Comment: Is this a Play application?

Comment: Did you read Play framework documentation? There is a dedicated section about how to write JSON using Play JSON library...

Comment: please look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the types of these parameters are, but if they are `String`, according to the official [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonHttp):

```scala
case class ResultCaseClass(country: String, countryPostcodeZones: String, placeholder: String)

implicit val resultWrites: Writes[ResultCaseClass] =
 ((JsPath \ “country").write[String] and
 (JsPath \ "countryPostcodeZones").write[String] and 
 (JsPath \ “placeholder").write[String] ) (unlift(ResultCaseClass.unapply))

def country(countryCode: String) = Authorized().async { implicit request =>
  val country = Country.find(countryCode).get

  val countryPostcodeZones = postcodeZones.get(country)

  val placeholder = countryPostcodeZones.postcodeType.placeholder  

  val result = ResultCaseClass(country, countryPostcodeZones, placeholder)

  val json = Json.toJson(result)
    
  Ok(json)
}
```

---

Note that for simple case classes like this you can also use a macro to generate the `Writes` automatically:

```scala
implicit val resultWrites: Writes[ResultCaseClass] = Json.writes[ResultCaseClass]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much :) it worked dear James I voted for your answer and it will be visible after "15 reputations" thank you so much!!